# Navigation Menu Bar with links

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement a navigation menu like the one shown below. I have attempted to put the html and css in the app.component but that doesn't work. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks !

[Picture of menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QC1Ov.png)

Comment: Did you include a picture?

Comment: Or code, or anything useful for us to help you?

Comment: I tried to include a picture and I got a message that I can't include pictures, which I don't understand how I can show an example of the menu that I am trying to implement.

Comment: You may want to look at Material sidenav here: https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview

Answer (score 0):

the only thing you need know is that you can use [routerLinkActive] directive see https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive, when the router are equal to the routerLink, you can asing a class or an array of class

e.g. with bootstrap 4.0.1

```
<ul class="nav flex-column">
  <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]='["link-active"]' [routerLinkActiveOptions]='{ exact: true }'>
    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]='["/"]'>Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]='["link-active"]' >
    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]='["/counter"]' >Counter</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]='["link-active"]' >
    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]='["/fetch-data"]' >Fech Data</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```